# iOS 8 Autolayout with Size Classes

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6, uistoryboard, size-classes

This is driving me crazy. All I need is to align the subview to superview & fill its bounds. To do this, all I used to do is create 4 Autolayout constraints for subview in storyboard and set top, left, bottom, right margins to 0 relative to subview. But in Xcode 6, with Size classes enabled, the left and right margins default to -16 and setting them to 0 has no effect. No matter what I do, the subview never fills superview bounds and there are few pixel gaps on the left and right. How do I get around it ?

FYI: This happens on iPhone 6+/iPad Air simulators.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will solve all your issues related to customised edge to edge issue.
I've highlighted the area from which you need to remove check mark.

Make sure if you are using auto layout then check pin is set to zero for all edges and constraints to margin is unchecked.
[image]

please remove checkmark from pin when adding constraints to view from super view. By default it will -16 even if you set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. However, I see another issue after using Autolayout. I am manually adding a CALayer to the subview now and setting its frame. The problem is now the centre of the layer is shifted downwards which I suspect is to do with navigation bar. If I do not set auto layout constraints and manually assign frames to views and then add CALayer, it is centered correctly. Any clues ?

Comment: If possible can you please add image and the code you have written it would be helpful what is causing your view to move down from center.

Comment: I caught the mistake. The view's top margin constraint was as 0 relative to top layout guide bottom rather than top.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, Accept the answer if it has solved your problem.