# Layout issue, Autolayout enabled but doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios

Below is my app when run on iPhone 6 simulator

As you might have guessed it looks good on iPhone 5.

Autoresize is on, but I'm not sure i fully grasp the concept, so i might be missing something.

Any suggestions for a solution are appreciated. 
I also added another image for the storyboard structure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set any constraints on your table view?  It looks like you just plopped it in there with no constraints, so on iPhone 6 iOS is doing its best to lay it out and just positioning it at the top left, probably at 320x480 pt size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto layout is *on* but you are not *using* it. You need to add *constraints* so that when the main view is resized to fit the screen, the table view is resized along with it. Otherwise, it just stays at the same size you designed it (which happens to be the right size for an iPhone 5). These devices are *different sizes*; the idea of auto layout is to cope with that difference. Use it.

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible as you might have not set layout constraints. The below link will help you how to set constraints. In the below link i've used size class but it is not necessary for you to use sane view, similar constraints can be applied to the storyboard structure you have used.

Hi please visit below link:
[iOS 8 Autolayout with Size Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816569/ios-8-autolayout-with-size-classes/26817297#26817297)

Advance auto layout Constraints:
[Adjust Center of Measure in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953168/adjust-center-of-measure-in-xcode-6/26191428#26191428)